# How to prefix LWC Combobox items with fixed static text?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to prefix some static text i.e.Sort by: to options in lightning combobox like in below image, please help how to do it
[image]

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far and what issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should utilize a label.

```
<lightning-combobox
        name="SortBy"
        label="Sort by"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Sort by..."
        options={options}
        onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

What you are specifically asking for (in the image) is not possible.